# crontab and shellscript

Tags: scripts, cron

If I have a shell script that must do a job 5 times a day at different time according to a specific table,
now, I must run for manually each time
how I can make it do the job automatically by executing the script once a day?

My suggestion for this issue:

1. use *"contactab * * * * * /shell/script"*.

**"but this display alarm not a regular file."**

2. use infinite loop.

Can anyone help me with how to do this?

Comment: Are you saying that the same shell script must run five times each day, but perhaps at different times each day according to a table? Or are you saying that you want to run a single shell script once daily that creates five jobs that run at different times? Must it be a cron-based solution, or are you open to alternatives like `at` or `systemd-run`? Do these jobs run as root? Or as a user?

Comment: What does it mean "but this display alarm not a regular file"? I can't understand it. Please describe your problem as precisely and as detailed as possible.

Comment: @user535733 The same shell script must run five times each day, but perhaps at different times each day according to a table
and yes i can use at or systemd-run
It is run as root

Comment: If you wish to use root cron, this can be very easy. Create a different crontab file for each unique entry in your table. Each day, copy the appropriate file into /etc/cron.d/ (and delete or overwrite yesterday;s copy). Root cron will run the jobs at the times indicated on the file. You can automate the daily file replacement with a simple script that runs once daily. Using systemd instead of cron is basically the same theory, but the formatting and commands are a bit different.

Comment: You could also program the script in a way so that it runs every 5 minutes with cron. But the script itself only triggers when it hits the designated time of the day, maybe specified in a table file. Use your imagination here. 